# URL as user input to a batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can I provide a user input as a URL link?

I want to provide an input like below

```
test.bat https://jazz-test.com/abc/XYZ_RST#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=15874&tab=com.ibm.team.workitem.tab.links
```

and the batch script should assign this to a variable

But only this portion is considered `https://jazz-test.com/abc/XYZ_RST#action`. Do I need to add anything else to consider the entire url as a single input

Comment: quote your argument: `t.bat "https://jazz-test.com/abc/XYZ_RST#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=15874&tab=com.ibm.team.workitem.tab.links"`. Use `%~1` to remove the quotes (if needed). Remember to *always* quote the variable (because of the poison char(s)) when you use it: `echo "%~1"`

Comment: quotes do work.. but yes I want to remove the quotes and tried with %~1
But then again the same result.
Only the portion until & is taken 
This came ::  

https://jazz-test.com/abc/XYZ_RST#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem

This is left :: &id=15874&tab=com.ibm.team.workitem.tab.links

Comment: yes - that's by design. There are some "poison chars" that have a special meaning, like `&|<>`and (depending on context) some more. You need to either quote the string ('echo"A&B"`) or escape those chars (`echo A^&B`). Or you use delayed expansion, like @aschipfl suggested.

Comment: What's your use case for using the string unquoted (show the code that actually fails with quotes)? Afaik, quoting should work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double-quotes (") with the URL

```
test.bat "https://jazz-test.com/abc/XYZ_RST#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=15874&tab=com.ibm.team.workitem.tab.links"
```

But If your batch file fails to execute the command because of the double-quotes then you need to add some code into the batch file for removing the comma

```
@echo off
set url=%1
set url=%url:~1,-1%
echo %url%
pause
```

Hope It works!

Comment: No, this won't work! 1. Use `set "url=%~1"` to remove the quotation marks (these are not inverted commas!). 2. `echo %url%` will fail because of the ampersands `&`; to safely output them, use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html): `echo(!url!`.

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you it is working !! Now I am passing the URL within quotes and while retrieving, the quotes are removed